# php, why i get duplicate content back from a foreach loop?

Tags: php, str-replace

i've got a query and i try to get some results like this:

```
    while ($keywords = mysql_fetch_array($keys1)){
    foreach ($keywords as $key) {
        $pos2 = strripos($key, $dquote);
            if ($pos2 === false) { } else { 
                $clean_dquote = str_replace('"', "", $key);
                print_r($clean_dquote);
                echo '<br>';
            } 
    }
}
```

the raw result from the `while` loop will be :

```
"test"
"test1"
```

i am using `str_replace` to make it look like this:

```
test
test1
```

what happens is that i get back:

```
test
test
test1
test1
```

is that because i use a `while` and a `foreach`?, but if i take one out i don't get no results

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: `if ($pos2 === false) { } else {` → `if ($pos2 !== false) {`

Comment: try replace 'while ($keywords = mysql_fetch_array($keys1))' with 'while ($keywords = mysql_fetch_array($keys1,MYSQL_ASSOC))'

Comment: @MichaelBai: Sharp! I think we have a winner here. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. 
The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).